# How can my Chinavasion TechPad Tablet be put in standby mode

Tags: tablet, standby

My Android Tablet. (TechPad 7" Tablet from Chinavasion, S3C6410 Android 1.6;) has an option to dim the screen after 2-10 minutes of inactivity.  However, there is no option to put it into a "standby" mode, and a full reboot takes 20-30 seconds.

Any ideas how to really put it into a standby / hibernate mode?

Comment: So does pressing the power button turn it off completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not support a standby or hibernate mode.